# Restrict a role in postgres to access some schemas in a database and don't list any other databases

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.04, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.3 under ubuntu 9.04. I access my database server using a console client or Pgadmin III.
Currently, I need to restrict access to only a couple of schemas in a database and also don't show other databases in the server.

For example, my current postgres server has the following databases:

```
postgres-8.3-server
|-- db1
|   |-- sch_a
|   |-- sch_b
|   |-- sch_c
|   `-- sch_d
|-- db2
|   |-- sch_e
|   |-- sch_f
|   `-- sch_g
`-- db3
    `-- sch_h
```

I need to restrict role "joe" to access only db2's sch_e and shc_g, and also don't show the other schemas in the same database.
When listing databases the output should be:

```
postgres-8.3-server
|-- db2
    |-- sch_e
    `-- sch_g
```

My current solution restricts schema and database access but I can still see the database name list. When I try to access any of them (except the one I'm allowed to) I receive a message about a specific entry not found at pg_hba.conf file, which is good but not ideal.

I'm currently checking the manual and googling for more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't restrict the ability to see which databases exist. Why does that matter, though, since you can restrict the ability to connect?

If you prefer a different error message, you might try letting people through pg_hba.conf and then restricting the CONNECT permission on the database itself (REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE foo FROM public; GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE foo TO somerole;")

Comment: Thanks Magnus. The databases names are important because they have client names appended to them. Restricting database access with pg_hba.conf and the revoking connect are great but only gives database level restriction. Is there a way to restrict visibility per schema? To only list some "visible" schemas that the user (role) has privileges.